# Why minmax() function inside of the repeat() function is not working properly with two constant values?

Tags: html, css

The code is not responsive, even I am using repeat(autofit,minmax()).

```css
div.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 300px));
}

.box {
  background-color: rgb(152, 152, 218);
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
  <div class="box">8</div>
  <div class="box">9</div>
  <div class="box">10</div>
</div>
```

The code is working like I just wrote repeat(autofit, column_width)

```css
div.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 300px);
}

.box {
  background-color: rgb(152, 152, 218);
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
  <div class="box">8</div>
  <div class="box">9</div>
  <div class="box">10</div>
</div>
```

I am a beiginner and can't find the reason !

**P.S** - The code is working properly if I am using **1fr** as the max_width in minmax()

Comment: your code is working fine, both produces the same result

Comment: Yes, that is the issue. While max-width is 1fr it is producing different result, and when I am using any constant value (like - 300px), it is not working properly